# Run Mocha HTML Tests in Browserstack / DOM Testing in Cloud

Tags: selenium, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai, browserstack

I'm trying to run DOM tests that I have written using Mocha and Chai for `assert` on Browserstack.

I have an HTML file `test.html` that looks like this:

```html
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.js"></script>

    <script class="mocha-init">
      mocha.setup('bdd');
      mocha.checkLeaks();
      assert = chai.assert;
    </script>
    <script src="MY_DOM_TESTS.js"></script>
    <script class="mocha-exec">
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
```

When I open this file in the browser locally, it runs through and shows me that all tests pass. My question now is how I can run it in one of the testing clouds, for example Browserstack.

They seem to have many adapters and plugins, but nothing explains this simple use case of DOM tests in an HTML file. Everything seems to be about `js` files exclusively, but not for HTML files.

I have tried using Karma with their plugins `karma-mocha` and `karma-browserstack-launcher`, to no avail. I tried having Karma run this simple test file but not even that seems to work:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        files: [
            './tests/test.html',
        ],
        client: {
            mocha: {
                reporter: 'html',
                ui: 'bdd',
            },
        },
```

Question: How can I run DOM tests using above HTML file in Browserstack (or any other Selenium testing cloud for that matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. You need to use their `local` testing (the name is misleading), which basically opens a local server and pipes through local files to browserstack. I created a minimum example here on how to run mocha dom tests inside an HTML file on browserstack:

https://github.com/fritzfr/mocha-html-browserstack-bridge

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for showing your interest in running tests on the remote cloud using Browserstack.

I did read through your query and could find that you want to run HTML DOM Tests on Browserstack, however, that is NOT supported and would require you to use a JS testing framework and write your tests accordingly in order to run tests.
Also, the documents you have referred are the required necessity in order to run JS Tests.

Please note you can use different Javascript unit testing frameworks such as QUnit, Jasmine, Mocha, and others to write our first unit test, and the same you can refer to the following documentation:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/javascript-testing/getting-started

Regards,
Browserstack Support